# Is it possible to upgrade my HTC Legend to Froyo without waiting for over the air updates?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-legend

I've heard that HTC has released its version of Froyo already on some other phones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTC now has an [official way](http://www.htc.com/au/SupportViewNews.aspx?dl_id=1074&news_id=852) for Vodafone users to do this

Answer (score 4):

Use [ROM Manager](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-koushikdutta-rommanager-nptD.aspx) to install [this ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=870662) from XDA.  You need to have root.  Otherwise just wait, I'm sure it won't be long till you get the OTA update since it was supposed to be released by all carriers yesterday.

Comment: So, if I want to keep Sense UI, I have to wait for my carrier to get round to deploying it?

Comment: There's probably a ROM with Sense too, just search XDA :)